# set input value by selected option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what I am trying to do is to set the kabelname, which is setted by selcted options into the input field by ordering the name like the order of the option fields.

This should happen by selecting or deselecting a option and wihout overwritting the whole input fild. It should only add or remove the values of the selected option.

If a kabelart is selected and steckertyp 1, the value of steckertyp1 should be added with a "-" to the value of kabelart into the input field of kabelname.

Then if a Verwendung is selected it should be added to kabelname with a "." and the value. Else if Verwendung is selected but Steckertyp isn´t, it schould be added with a "-" to kabelname.

The same thing shoul happen with Anschlusstyp...

If kabelart is setted to "", then kabelname should be cleared. But if one of the other options is changed or setted to "" it only should be removed on its position.

I´m sorry for that bad describtion but I hope you know what I mean. If not feel free to ask.

Thank you

```js
function changedKabelart(kabelartValue){
  var kaValue = kabelartValue;
  
  if(kaValue != ""){      
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value = kaValue;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value = kaValue;     
  }
}

/* Steckertyp 1 */
function changedSteckertyp1(sttyp1Value){
  var st1Value = sttyp1Value;
  
  if(st1Value != ""){
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value += "-" + st1Value;
  }
  else{          
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value += st1Value;
  }          
}

/* Verwendung */
function changedVerwendung(verwendungValue){
  var vwValue = verwendungValue;
  var st1Value = document.getElementById("steckertyp1").value;
  
  
  if(vwValue != "" && st1Value != ""){
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value += "." + vwValue;
  }
  else if(vwValue != "" && st1Value == ""){
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value += "-" + vwValue;
  }
  else{          
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value += vwValue;
  }          
}
      
/* Anschlusstyp 1 */
function changedAnschluss1(anschluss1Value){
  var ansch1Value = anschluss1Value;
  
  if(ansch1Value != ""){
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value += "-" + ansch1Value;
  }
  else{            
    document.getElementById("kabelname").value += ansch1Value;
  }          
}
```

```html
<p> Kabelart </p>
<select name="kabelart" id="kabelart" required onchange="changedKabelart(this.value);"> 
  <option value="" selected></option>   
  <option value="K" > Kabel</option>   
  <option value="K2" > Kabel 2</option>   
  <option value="K3" > Kabel 3</option>   
</select>

<p> Steckertyp </p>
<select name="steckertyp1" id="steckertyp1" onchange="changedSteckertyp1(this.value);">
  <option value="" selected></option>
  <option value="ST1" >ST1</option>
  <option value="ST2" >ST2</option>
  <option value="ST3" >ST3</option>
</select>

<p> Verwendung </p>
<select name="verwendung" id="verwendung" onchange="changedVerwendung(this.value);" >
  <option value="" selected></option>   
  <option value="VW1" >VW1</option>   
  <option value="VW2" >VW1</option>   
</select>

<p> Anschlusstyp </p>
<select name="anschlusstyp1" id="anschlusstyp1" onchange="changedAnschluss1(this.value);" >
  <option value="" selected></option>  
  <option value="A1" >A1</option>  
  <option value="A2" >A2</option>  
  <option value="A3" >A3</option>  
</select>

<br><br><br>
<input type="text" name="kabelname" id="kabelname" placeholder="Kabelname" readonly />
```

Comment: You missed the value for "st1Value" in the function "changedVerwendung". Please update it.

Comment: done... but this wasn´t the main problem ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using different functions to update kabelname, use only one. Then everything will be covered.

```
            <p> Kabelart </p>
        <select name="kabelart" id="kabelart" required onchange="update();"> 
          <option value="" selected></option>   
          <option value="K" > Kabel</option>   
          <option value="K2" > Kabel 2</option>   
          <option value="K3" > Kabel 3</option>   
        </select>

        <p> Steckertyp </p>
        <select name="steckertyp1" id="steckertyp1" onchange="update();">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option value="ST1" >ST1</option>
          <option value="ST2" >ST2</option>
          <option value="ST3" >ST3</option>
        </select>

        <p> Verwendung </p>
        <select name="verwendung" id="verwendung" onchange="update();" >
          <option value="" selected></option>   
          <option value="VW1" >VW1</option>   
          <option value="VW2" >VW1</option>   
        </select>

        <p> Anschlusstyp </p>
        <select name="anschlusstyp1" id="anschlusstyp1" onchange="update();" >
          <option value="" selected></option>  
          <option value="A1" >A1</option>  
          <option value="A2" >A2</option>  
          <option value="A3" >A3</option>  
        </select>

        <br><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="kabelname" id="kabelname" placeholder="Kabelname" readonly />


        <script>
        function update() {
            var kabelname ;
            if(document.getElementById("kabelart").value === "") {  
              kabelname = "";
            }
            else {
                kabelname = document.getElementById("kabelart").value;

                if(document.getElementById("steckertyp1").value!== ""){
                    kabelname += "-" + document.getElementById("steckertyp1").value;
                    if(document.getElementById("verwendung").value !== "") {
                        kabelname += "." + document.getElementById("verwendung").value;
                        if(document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value!== "") {
                            kabelname += "-" + document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value!== "") {
                            kabelname += "." + document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value;
                        }    
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(document.getElementById("verwendung").value !== "") {
                        kabelname += "-" + document.getElementById("verwendung").value;
                        if(document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value!== "") {
                            kabelname += "." + document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value!== "") {
                            kabelname += "-" + document.getElementById("anschlusstyp1").value;
                        }                            
                    }
                }

            }                
            document.getElementById("kabelname").value = kabelname;                
        }

        </script>
```